How can I write my functions logic better?
I feel this logic could be improved
# check existence of credentials, if it exists rewrite it.
def check_credentials_file(credentials_file):
    if os.path.exists(credentials_file):
        choice = input("File already found, do you want to rewrite it? y/n: ").lower()
        if choice == "y":
            os.remove(credentials_file)
            return True
        else:
            print("No new file was created...")
            return False
    else:
        print("Creating new File...")
        return True


def create_credentials_file(user, passw, domain, credentials_file):
    try:
        print(f"{credentials_file}")
        with open(credentials_file, "w") as file:
            file.write(f"username={user}\n")
            file.write(f"password={passw}\n")
            file.write(f"domain={domain}\n")
        print("File created")
    except IOError as error:
        print(f"Can't create file: {error}")


def main():
    if check_credentials_file(credentials_filepath):
        create_credentials_file(
            samba_user, samba_pass, samba_domain, credentials_filepath
        )
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

I feel I am doing so much circles and there should be a better way, specially with the function check_credentials_file and the call. Or does it look good?

If your code works, but you want to make it work better you should probably be asking on https://codereview.stackexchange.com.

Before you post at [codereview.se], be sure to read A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users, as some things are done differently over there - e.g. question titles should simply say what the code is for, as the question is always, "How can I improve this?".  Be sure that the code works correctly; include your unit tests if possible.  You'll likely get some suggestions on making it more efficient, easier to read, and better tested.

Your code looks fine but there are simpler ways to write it. For example;
def create_credentials_file(user, passw, domain, credentials_file):
    try:
        print(f"{credentials_file}")
        if os.path.exists(credentials_file):  # File Exists Already
            overwrite = input("File already found, do you want to rewrite it? y/n: ").lower() == "y"
            if not overwrite:  # We Shouldn't Overwrite it
                print("File Not Created..")
                return
        with open(credentials_file, "w") as file:  # We don't need to remove the file as the "w" flag will overwrite 
                                                   # the file anyway. the "a" or append flag will add to the already 
                                                   # exsiting file
            file.write(f"username={user}\n")
            file.write(f"password={passw}\n")
            file.write(f"domain={domain}\n")
        print("File created")
    except IOError as error:
        print(f"Can't create file: {error}")


def main():
    create_credentials_file(
        samba_user, samba_pass, samba_domain, credentials_filepath)
    
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

